# Best way to force Antivirus scan on removable drive

Tags: anti-virus

Is there any way to force antivirus to scan USB once plugged, either in Symantec or Mcafee.

Comment: Most likely, "yes".  

You will need to update your question to indicate which specific products and versions you intend to use. The configuration for each will vary based on this information. As it stands now, you note two *company* names, not products.

Comment: sorry about that in McAfee VSE 8.7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you cannot do this currently with VSE. You can configure it to scan a drive once you open it in Explorer, but this is not ideal especially if there is an autorun app on there.

They do seem to offer [another product](http://download.mcafee.com/products/manuals/en-gb/vsusb_datasheet_2007.pdf) which does it, not sure how this fits it.

I would suggest talking to McAfee.

Comment: ok isn't there any script or batch can do this ?